# How to disable a drive for a particular user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I'm running windows server 2012. I've just made a new account for a friend of mine. Now I don't want him to be able to see my D drive. Is it possible to disable a drive for an account?

Comment: Sure; change his user group to one that does not have access to the drive; create said user group of required

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the drive -> properties -> security

There you can add the user and his new permissions.